# Lenses, the State monad, and Maps with known keys

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

here is a puzzle that I keep on bumping into and that, I believe, no previous SO question has been addressing: How can I best use the `lens` library to set or get values within a `State` monad managing a nested data structure that involves `Map`s **when I know for a fact that certain keys are present in the maps involved**?

## Here is the puzzle

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, DerivingVia #-}

import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Except
import Control.Lens
import Data.Maybe
import Control.Monad
import Data.Map

type M = StateT World (ExceptT String Identity)

data World = World
  { _users      :: Map UserId User
  , _otherStuff :: Int
  }

type UserId = Int

data User = User
  { _balance     :: Balance
  , _moreStuff   :: Int
  }

newtype Balance = Balance Int
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Num) via Int

makeLenses 'World
makeLenses 'User

deleteUser :: UserId -> M ()
deleteUser uid = do
   user <- use $ users . at uid
   unless (isJust user) (throwError "unknown user")

   -- from here on we know the users exists.

   -- Question: how should the following lens look like?
   balance <- use $ users . ix uid . balance
   when (balance < 0) (throwError "you first have to settle your debt")
   when (balance > 0) (throwError "you first have to withdraw the remaining balance")

   users . at uid .= Nothing
```

## Attempt 1: using `ix`

The snippet above is using `ix`.

```hs
   balance <- use $ users . ix uid . balance
```

This yields a `Traversal`, so it may focus on multiple elements or none at all. In the context of `use` this means we need a `Monoid` and a `Semigroup` instance. In fact, this is what GHC has to say:

```
    • No instance for (Monoid Balance) arising from a use of ‘ix’
    • In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘ix uid’
      In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘ix uid . balance’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘users . ix uid . balance’
   |
45 |    balance <- use $ users . ix uid . balance
```

There is no good way to implement `<>` for `Balance`. I could just implement addition, or use `error`, because, in fact, this function will never be called. But is this the cleanest way to do this?

## Attempt 2: using `at`

Another option seems to be using `at`.

```hs
   balance <- use $ users . at uid . balance
```

This yields a `Lens` that focuses on a `Maybe User`. This means, the follow-up lens `balance` has the wrong type.

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘User’
                     with ‘Maybe (IxValue (Map UserId User))’
      Expected type: (User -> Const Balance User)
                     -> Map UserId User -> Const Balance (Map UserId User)
        Actual type: (Maybe (IxValue (Map UserId User))
                      -> Const Balance (Maybe (IxValue (Map UserId User))))
                     -> Map UserId User -> Const Balance (Map UserId User)
    • In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘at uid’
      In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘at uid . balance’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘users . at uid . balance’
```

## Attempt 3: working with `at`'s `Maybe`

Let's try to work with that `Maybe`

```hs
   balance <- use $ users . at uid . _Just . balance
```

This time, we have a `Prism`, which needs to deal with the situation when it has to work with `Nothing`. So we are back at requiring a `Monoid`.

```
    • No instance for (Monoid Balance) arising from a use of ‘_Just’
    • In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘_Just’
      In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘_Just . balance’
      In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘at uid . _Just . balance’
```

## Attempt 3b: working with `at`'s `Maybe`

Let's try another way to work with that `Maybe`

```hs
   balance <- use $ users . at uid . non undefined . balance
```

From the documentation:

> If v is an element of a type a, and a' is a sans the element v, then non v is an isomorphism from Maybe a' to a.

We can use `undefined`, `error` or any "empty" `User` we want, it does not matter, since this case is never triggered, given the user id is present in the map.

For this to work we need `Eq` for `User`, which is fair enough. And it compiles and seems to work; that is, for reading. For writing, there is an, initially, unexpected twist:

```hs
topUp :: UserId -> Balance -> M ()
topUp uid b = do
   user <- use $ users . at uid
   unless (isJust user) (throwError "unknown user")

   users . at uid . non undefined . balance += b
```

Running this blows up

```
experiment-exe: Prelude.undefined
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at libraries/base/GHC/Err.hs:79:14 in base:GHC.Err
  undefined, called at app/Main.hs:55:25 in main:Main
```

The explanation is that when writing, we use the optics "right-to-left", and in this direction `non` is injecting the `User` we provide as its parameter. Replacing `undefined` with a "empty" `User` obscures this mistake. It always replaces the existing user with the empty user, effectively loosing the user's initial balance when trying to top-up.

## Conclusion

So, I have found options to make this work for reading, but none seems to be convincing. And I could not figure this out for writing.

What is your recommendation? How should that lens be constructed?

Edit: moved solution to self answer.

Comment: Perhaps `maybeToExceptT`?

Comment: If you _know for a fact_ that the keys are present, then how about just not storing them in a map?

Comment: Are you willing to use `justified-containers`?

Comment: I'm not a lens expert, and I can't remember off-hand whether traversals are enough for writing. Does `users . at uid . traversed . balance += b` work?

Comment: Thanks @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica. I wasn't aware of `justified-containers`. Do you have experience with using it in combination with Lenses?

Comment: Oh, wow, @DanielWagner, this works! Thanks so much!

Comment: I suggest moving the "Edit - Solution" section to a self-answer. (Attribution for the suggestions by other people can be provided by linking to the answers/comments they came from.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is:

- `balance <- use $ users . at uid . to fromJust . balance` for reading ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71046966/542390))
- `users . at uid . traversed . balance += b` for writing ([see this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71046129/lenses-the-state-monad-and-maps-with-known-keys?noredirect=1#comment125605134_71046129))

And this lens works for reading and writing:

- `users . unsafeSingular (ix uid) . balance` ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71055765/542390))

Answer (score 3):

If you are *sure* that the key is present then you can use [`fromJust`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromJust) to turn the `Maybe User` into a `User`:

```
balance <- use $ users . at uid . to fromJust . balance
```

Although as a design issue I'd suggest replacing `use $ users . at uid ...` with functions that throw a meaningful error:

```
getUser :: UserId -> M User
```

And for handy lens accessing:

```
getsUser :: UserId -> Getter User a -> M a
```

Then just call one of those every time you want to look up a user. That way you don't have to have a separate check at the head of your function.

Answer (score 2):

The most direct facilities `lens` has for doing this are unsafe operations that treat a traversal that you "know" will target only one element as if it were a lens.  As you're probably aware, there's an operator for this that serves as a variation of `^.` or `^?`:

```
s <- get
let user = s ^?! users . at uid
```

but for `view` (within a `Reader`) or `use` (within a `State`), there don't seem to be any built-in variations. You can write your own using the `unsafeSingular` function in `Control.Lens.Traversal` though:

```
use1 :: MonadState s m => Traversal' s a -> m a
use1 = use . unsafeSingular

view1 :: MonadReader s m => Traversal' s a -> m a
view1 = view . unsafeSingular
```

after which:

```
balance <- use1 $ users . ix uid . balance
```

should work.

If you would rather make the optic itself unsafe rather  using a safe optic unsafely, you can use `unsafeSingular` directly to modify the optic.  For example:

```
balance <- use $ users . unsafeSingular (ix uid) . balance
```